# Batch scripting, mutlple finds and multple do sets

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

At the moment I am running the following to get some information from 'systeminfo', however it needs to run systeminfo twice which takes some time. How would I be able to do multple 'Find"XXX" do sets'?

```
For /f "delims=" %%A IN ('systeminfo ^| Find "OS Name"') DO Set "VarA=%%A"
For /f "delims=" %%A IN ('systeminfo ^| Find "BIOS Version"') DO Set "VarB=%%A"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `systeminfo` gives output in your local language (exampe: german: `Betriebssystemname` and `BIOS-Version`(note the hyphen)). I suggest using `wmic os get caption /value` and `wmic bios get caption /value`  instead. That aside, you could use a temporary file (`sysinfo>temp.txt`) and parse the file twice (or more, if you need more infos)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ended up using the following to find out the information i wanted about adapter information: ------netsh interface ip show addresses "Local Area Connection" |findstr "IP Address"---- :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies guys.

I wanted to set the bit version windows the batch file would run on, I figured it out ages ago but thought I would post it here for those that came across it:

```
echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% | find "64" > NUL
If %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (Set bit=64) else (Set bit=32)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You posted a solution to your actual problem, but this is not an answer to the question that you asked.

Answer (score 2):

Next code snippet could work (note `set` commands are merely `ECHO`ed for debugging purposes; remove capitalized `ECHO` no sooner than debugged):

```
For /f "delims=" %%A IN ('systeminfo') DO (
   For /F "delims=" %%G IN ('echo %%A ^| Find /I "OS Name"') Do ECHO Set "VarA=%%A"
   For /F "delims=" %%G IN ('echo %%A ^| Find /I "BIOS Version"') DO ECHO Set "VarB=%%A" 
)
```

However, follow Stephan's advice and parse `wmic` output rather (do not forget `/value` option). To do that correctly, note great Dave Benham's article *[`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)*

Answer (score 0):

I too would use WMIC, but there is a simple solution if you want to use SYSTEMINFO - use FINDSTR with two /C:"search strings"

```
for /f "tokens=1,2*" %A in ('systeminfo ^| findstr /c:"OS Name" /c:"BIOS Version"') do set "%A=%C"
```

The above will define two variables on an English machine: OS and BIOS.